# want to create /resources route in laravel but there is also directory called resources in laravel so how to handle that?

Tags: laravel

I want to create '/resources' route in Laravel but there is also directory called 'resources' in laravel so how to handle that ?

currently it is showing resources directory instead of executing route.

Comment: If public/resources exists, you can't use that as a route in the router.  The router is only run when files/directories don't exist.  Look at .htaccess to see how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actual directory overwriting Laravel route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063959/actual-directory-overwriting-laravel-route)

Comment: Your domain must be loading at the "public" folder, not at the Laravel root. There is no "resources" folder in the "public" folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the default `resources` folder on laravel are in the root directory, not into public directory.

When you access a Laravel URL, eg. `http://localhost/xyz`, first the server will
search for a `xyz` file inside `public` folder, if it exists it will be served, otherwise the `index.php` will be called and then Laravel try to resolve the route.

Answer (score 0):

solved by public/.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /resources
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```